# javascript on iOS Swift need to wait until dynamic content is loaded via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xmlhttprequest, wkwebview

Im trying to get all URLs with an extension of .pdf from a page, using WKScriptMessageHandler.The pdf urls are not exposed to the page until user click on an element that loads these URLS.

This is what I use to "click" on all the elements and it exposes the pdf URLs.

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('[onclick*="javascript:ExpCollGroup"]');

                for (var node of element){
                     node.click();
                }
```

I now need to extract all these URLs so the script continues with

```
 var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".pdf"]');

          for (var circular of nodes){
               urls.push(circular.getAttributeNode('href').nodeValue);
            }


           if (urls.length > 0){
              window.webkit.messageHandlers.didFetchURLsFromServer.postMessage(urls);


            }
```

The nodes array is empty so the rest of the code doesn't run really.

full script below

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("""

        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {

           var urls = [];
           var element = document.querySelectorAll('[onclick*="javascript:ExpCollGroup"]');

            for (var node of element){
                 node.click();
            }

//The code below runs before the loop has loaded its content
//Preventing the nodes array from being populated.
//The only thing that seems to work is setting setTimeout function. 
//I guess I need a call back when node.click() runs its last action of the loop

           var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".pdf"]');

          for (var circular of nodes){
               urls.push(circular.getAttributeNode('href').nodeValue);
            }


           if (urls.length > 0){
              window.webkit.messageHandlers.didFetchURLsFromServer.postMessage(urls);
              }


    }

                    """, completionHandler: nil)
```

it is if the document does not take into account the newly present anchor tags with the required URLs. When I run same script in safari desktop it works but on iOS the urls Array stays at length of 0.

I've tried using Promise but is not fired on iOS but works in desktop safari.
Tips very much appreciated. 
Note: Webpage is not mine

Comment: `javascript:` is not needed in an inline event handler

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: You likely want some kind of setTimeout to wait until the click has loaded the content or add your code to the end of `ExpCollGroup`

Comment: I have used a timeout and that does work just looking for something that isn't relying on setting enough "timeout" and instead works off a call back If possible